# how can i position my text

Tags: javascript, html, random, position

i just started with programming for a school project, so i a big noob in programming. i hope somebody can help me with my problem.

i want to create 5 random numbers in a pentagon position,

how can i get these numbers in the good position?
this is what my code looks like:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

document.getElementById("deemo").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

document.getElementById("deeemo").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

document.getElementById("demmo").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>random number</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <p>random number</p>

  <p id="deemo"></p>


  <p>random number</p>

  <p id="deeemo"></p>



  <p>random number</p>

  <p id="demmo"></p>


  <p>random number</p>

  <p id="demoo"></p>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'pentagon position'? You mean that you want to generate 5 random numbers and then position them on the page so that they form a pentagon?

Comment: A better description of "pentagon position" would be helpful. A paint doodle would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to spell each of the Id correctly because you have used deeemo somewhere and demmo somewhere. 
This kind of program can be written by using loops like similarly like high school Java programming.
Take help of css

`positio:fixed;
top:10px;
right:10px;
left and bottom similarly.`
And make each div for each number and positon them as you need try out with one div and play with position attr of css you can place it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly , i think you are trying to do something like this:

```
<html>

<body>

  <span style="margin-left: 200px">random number</span>

  <span id="demo"></span>
<br> 
<br>
  <span style="margin-left: 50px">random number</span>
  <span id="deemo"></span>

  <span style="margin-left:200px" >random number</span>    
  <span id="deeemo"></span>
<br>
<br>

  <span style="margin-left: 50px">random number</span>
  <span id="demmo"></span>

  <span style="margin-left: 200px">random number</span>
  <span id="demoo"></span>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I changed `<p>` with `<span>` because `<p>` creates linebreaks every time called.

Comment: ps, you can add these styling to css, and position it as you want